# Java Vs C++ Memory Allocation

Tags: java, c++

Example in c++

```
Employee emp=new Employee();
```

Now here **x** bytes are created to store Employee. And **y** bytes are required to store reference. Hence **x+y** bytes are required.

Now in c++ since there is no garbage collection, its programmers duty to destroy the object.

Employee emp2=emp;

**Question1:** Now does it create one more address space of **(x+y)** for emp2 ?

In Java

It just points to the object in heap.

**Question2 :** So does this mean if the same object is added into a ArrayList in java, lets say 100 times then the memory used is only to store the reference of the object in heap? **i.e only 100*y+x amount of memory will be used?**

Comment: yes (to the heap or the stack, depending where you are allocating it...)

Comment: "Example in C" ?! No that's not even C++ (missing a *) ! Don't try to do a three-way language compare when you're still struggling with 2.

Comment: @MSalters Actially, more likely to be Java than C++ (`Employee` would need an implicit conversion from `Employee*` for the latter.)

Comment: @juanchopanza: Yeah, I realized that a few seconds later when my mind switched from C to C++ mode and it still didn't parse ;)

Comment: Is *Question1* in for C/C++?. I am confused because it seems to be written in Java :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**So does this mean if the same object is added into a ArrayList in java, lets say 100 times then the memory used is only to store the reference of the object in heap? i.e only 100*y+x amount of memory will be used?** - Yes. In *collections* only references to actual objects (which are almost always on heap) are added.

As a side note, java has *4-byte references* irrespective of the architecture (32 bit / 64 bit).

Comment: Could you add an example of one *not* being on the heap?

Comment: Escape analysis could lead to stack allocation of objects

Answer (score 1):

There is the **stack** memory of function calls' local variables; a stack as function calls are nested.

This is the memory for variables. In Java a reference to an object. The object itself is stored on the **heap**, garbage collected. Also an array is an Object in Java. Java does not have C structs on the stack. *This is a historical design decision to keep everything simple, as successor of "complex" C++.*

Now in C++ you have an immediate struct or array on the stack (without new/malloc). You then need a copy constructor, that shovels the data from one space to the other (stack or heap).

The effective difference is that in C one can have a linked list where every node is fat, with the data inside.
In Java, say a `LinkedList<T>` every node (a heap object) will contain an additional indirection, a reference to a T data object.
The data may be shared in Java, and are possibly copied in C.

From this perspective you can do your own calculations of memory usage. I feel the need to mention that Java's good garbage collection in general is better than malloc/free of C. So Java certainly is not that bad.

Comment: Java's GC is better than manual memory managment? ***That depends.***

Comment: I feel "in many situations" would better than "in general", too

Comment: I concur with both comments till now; @Deduplicator. And then there is `calloc` in C, stack data in C++. Benchmarks and real-world applications show an incredibly favored Java. Mostly due to heap fragmentation, suboptimal `free`, and - admittedly - a hotspot compiler exploiting knowing the running variant of processor. Still C can be faster, especially when not using OOP. Linus Torvalds picked C for Linux as he found OOP overdone. True at that time.

Comment: Correction: C `alloca` allocates memory on the stack, not `calloc`.